# Extracting moments of $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ from asymptotic behavior of $\mathbb{E}[(X_1^n+\cdots+X_k^n)^m]$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions

For fixed $k$ suppose we have $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ non-negative random variables with density functions.

Setting a): We know $\mathbb{E}[(X_1^n+\cdots+X_k^n)^m]$ exactly for any integers $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Setting b): We can approximate $\mathbb{E}[(X_1^n+\cdots+X_k^n)^m]$ up to some additive error $R_{m,n}$ with $\sup\limits_{m \in \mathbb{N}} |R_{m,n}| \cdot \mathbb{E}[(X_1^n+\cdots+X_k^n)^m]^{-1} \xrightarrow {n \rightarrow \infty} 0$.

Is there a nice way to extract the moments $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1,\ldots,X_k)^a]$?

There is some trickery one can do with the series expansion of the $n$-th root
\begin{align*}
& (1+x)^{\frac{a}{n}} = \sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\prod\limits_{l=0}^{r-1} (a-ln)}{r! n^r} x^r \ ,
\end{align*}
since the convergence $\mathbb{E}[(X_1^n+\cdots+X_k^n)^{\frac{a}{n}}] \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\max(X_1,\ldots,X_k)^a]$ holds (under mild integrability conditions). However, the calculations become nasty quickly. Is there a better way? For example a nice analytic function $f_n$, which is close enough to the $n$-th root for large values might make the process easier.

Any help is much apprechiated! Setting (a) is fine, but I am also interested in Setting (b).

Comment: (i) By "large $n$ and $m$", do you mean "all large $n$ and $m$"? (ii) To use the limit transition, you need small $m$ ($m\sim a/n$), not large. (iii) What do you mean by "extract"? Why not extract by the limit transition?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry only $n$ can be large and $m$ is an arbitrary integer. I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: When $m$ is an integer, I sadly can't directly find the limit, I have to go through the series representation of the $n$-th square root, which only works on the interval (0,2), which means I first have to rescale into the interval. The formulas quickly explode such that I am finding it difficult to find the limit, so I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: "for large $n$ and fixed integers $m \in \mathbb{N}$" is still not quite clear to me. Can you place formal quantifiers here: for each ... there are ...?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am currently in Setting (b), but am confident in getting to the exact values for Setting (a).

Comment: If upper bounds will suffice, you can probably get decent mileage out of the Markov inequality ${\bf P}(\max(X_1,\dots,X_k) \geq \lambda) \leq \lambda^{-nm} {\bf E} (X_1^n+\dots+X_k^n)^m$ and optimising in $n,m$, then writing ${\bf E} \max(X_1,\dots,X_k)^a = \int_0^\infty {\bf P}(\max(X_1,\dots,X_k) \geq \lambda) a \lambda^{a-1}\ d\lambda$.

Comment: @Tardis : There are two settings and, respectively, two questions in this post (apparently of quite different levels of difficulty). According to MathOverflow guidelines, there should be only one question in one post. So, I suggest these two questions be asked in two separate posts.